# Oracle userenv('terminal') equivalent in PostgreSQL

Tags: oracle, postgresql

In Oracle, `userenv('terminal')` returns the operating system identifier for the terminal of the current session.
On my windows machine, I got the hostname as a result of the following query in Oracle setup.

```
SQL> select userenv('terminal') from dual;
"DESKTOP-*******"
```

Is there any in-built function in Postgres that can get the same result? If not how do I get that on Postgres?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> returns the operating system identifier for the terminal of the current session

That's not exactly true. It returns whatever the SQL client sent for that property. It could well be "*So long, and thanks for the fish*".

If your ultimate goal is to get the hostname of the client in Postgres, you can use

```
select client_addr, client_hostname
from pg_stat_activity
where pid = pg_backend_pid();
```

However, `client_hostname` is only populated, if `log_hostname` is enabled in the Postgres [configuration file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-HOSTNAME).